# Video Processor MFT and deinterlacing

Tags: ms-media-foundation, interlacing

MSDN [Video Processor MFT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162913) mentions that the MFT can be used to deinterlace interlaced video.

I set the output Media type to the same as the input + the `MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE` to progressive on the output media type.

But the output samples are still interleaved.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test the Video Proccessor MFT because it needs Windows8/10. But i will say two things :

- The documentation says it is GPU accelerated, but does not say if it does fallback to software processing. So, if it's only GPU accelerated, and if your GPU does not support deinterlacing, it can explain that your frames are still interleaved. You can check [DXVAHD_PROCESSOR_CAPS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318439(v=vs.85).aspx).
- For a correct deinterlacing, sample needs to be assigned with some of those values : MFSampleExtension_Interlaced, MFSampleExtension_BottomFieldFirst, MFSampleExtension_RepeatFirstField , and so on ([Sample Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370442(v=vs.85).aspx)). So you can check if parser/decoder correctly set those values. If it is not, the Video Processor MFT will not be able to do deinterlacing.

Comment: I did not set the dxgidevicemanager yet. So I guess the gpu wasn't used yet. I will investigate it,  but it takes me a day or so to prepare the dx11 chain.  Haven't worked with dx11 yet.  But I remember the first time I had to prepare the output samples was not that easy